# How to see which game a Steam key is for?

Tags: steam

I bought a Steam key for some game, but when I add the key to Steam, I'm told that I already own the game. As I think the seller (not Steam itself) sold me a key for the wrong game, I'd like to get some proof of that. How can I see details corresponding to the key?

The game I wanted to buy is "Prey" released in 2006, but I think I got "Prey" released in 2017 (which I already own, from a previous failed attempt to buy the 2006 game). However, without some kind of proof that the key corresponds to "Prey" 2017, it's hard to get a refund.

Comment: I think your best bet is contacting the website where the bought the key from

Comment: @Riley I did, the won't budge and state the key is for the correct game.

Comment: @BlueRaja no, I don't care about the "first" part. I'd like to know the game at any point in time, even after attempting to use the key.

Comment: Prey (2006) is not available on Steam, so it's not possible for anyone to be selling Steam keys for it.

Comment: Interesting. https://www.cjs-cdkeys.com/de/products/Prey-%28old-game%29-CD-Key-For-Steam.html might be very problematic then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt to redeem a key for a game you already own, the "install" dialog should pop up. Installing the game should allow you to disambiguate what game it is for certain.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. It's indeed the wrong Prey (2017). I'll send the video to the seller to get a refund.

Comment: Why vote to close this as a duplicate and then still answer it?

Comment: @Joachim because OP pointed out why this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: A good time to remind people that close votes can be retracted by opening the dialog again.